# What is the purpose of "ext: 'jar'" in dependencies config?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy

I see a lot of build.gradle configs with this setting:

```
compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'jenkins-core', version: '+', ext: 'jar'
```

what is `ext: 'jar'` do?

ext is DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension but I can't find docs for what "jar" is.

If I take off the `ext: jar` in this example I get an error for what looks like a transitive dependency:

```
Could not find org.connectbot.jbcrypt:jbcrypt:1.0.0.
```

Is "jar" downloading a precompiled uber jar or something instead of a proper Maven package? Why is it there seems to be ZERO documentation for this- maybe I'm not looking in the right place?

### Edit

I found an explanation [here](http://tdongsi.github.io/blog/2018/02/09/intellij-setup-for-jenkins-shared-library-development/):

> NOTE 2: The ext: 'jar' is VERY important to ensure that jar files,
> instead of hpi/jpi files, are being downloaded and understood by
> IntellJ. Without that ext option specified, IntellJ won’t find JAR
> files nested in hpi/jpi files which is the default binaries for
> Jenkins plugins.

But I'm still confused what's happening. Is the argument "jar" being passed to the dependency and these Jenkins dependencies are aware of this "jar" argument? So jar isn't a standard Gradle dep thing, it's specific to these Jenkins deps?

Comment: I am not sure what your are asking but : JAR is a compressed java file. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

Comment: `ext` is short for "extension" - meaning the suffix (or "file extension") at the end of a file name - such as `txt` in the file name `notes.txt`. And `jar` is the file extension that is needed in your Gradle configuration, so that JAR files embedded inside the Jenkins plug-in can be found. A JAR file has `jar` as its file extension - so, for example, the file name in your question might be `jbcrypt.1.0.0.jar`. Apologies in advance if I'm explaining what you already know...

Comment: ...Jenkins plug-ins are a bit unusual because they are themselves zip files (which may  contain JAR files!) - but they use `hpi` or `jpi` as their file extensions: `my-jenkins-plugin.hpi`. This extra directive allows the `*.jar` files inside a `*.hpi` file to be located.

Comment: so `ext: jar` is searching for and downloading all *.jar files inside of the dependency/package I'm specifying? So I could specify any extension and it will just glob those specific files in the dependency? Think I'm still confused about what its actually doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the DSL documentation of [`DependencyHander`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#N16E3D

> There are two notations supported for declaring a dependency on an external module. One is a string notation formatted this way:
>
> `configurationName "group:name:version:classifier@extension"`
>
> The other is a map notation:
>
> `configurationName group: group, name: name, version: version, classifier: classifier, ext: extension`

And is further documented in the Javadoc:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/DependencyArtifact.html#getExtension--

> Returns the extension of this artifact. Often the extension is the same as the type, but sometimes this is not the case. For example for an ivy XML module descriptor, the type is *ivy* and the extension is *xml*.

Comment: but what is "jar"? Is it something only these specific dependencies understand?

Comment: I'm not sure how else it can be explained since that docs explain it already. It is the extension of the artifact.

Comment: why do I need to specify the extension in this case? Is the type "hpi" and the extension is "jar"? And its defaulting to looking for a file named ".hpi" but its actually named ".jar" ?